# How to re-open Property Inspector in JDeveloper 12c?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I recently closed the property inspector mistakenly in JDeveloper 12c. Now I can't find out how to re-open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

Windows and then Properties or cntr+shift+I